# put oldest file in log.txt on smbclient

Tags: linux, samba, smb

We have 94 PC's on 1 site. There is a folder that we need to check for the oldest file in that folder on each PC.

I can run a .txt file with all the IP's in a loop, but I don't know how to check and get the oldest file and add these in a log.txt. I need the name of that file in that log.

```
while read line; do

IP=$(echo $line | cut -d ';' -f 2)
NAME=$(echo $line | cut -d ';' -f 1)

smbclient  '\\'$IP'\C$' -W *** -U ***%*** -c "cd \*****\*****; get TheOldestFile" >> log.txt
```

Is this possible to do this with smbclient?

Comment: Is the core question here how to find the oldest file on some Windows PCs?

Comment: In a specific folder I want the name of the oldest file. This for 94PC's in a textfile (log.txt for example) with the name of the PC's and the name of the oldest file in that folder on that pc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks to me, based on the `cd \...` syntax, that you’re not dealing with a Unix PC.

Comment: As you can clearly see is this a bash file. This is placed on a Linux server. But these files I need are indeed on a windows PC. But I dont think that matters.

Comment: You’ve figured out the Linux side of the problem; it seems to me that the remainder is finding files on a Windows system.

Comment: on a Linux server in a bash file...

Comment: There are no Linux commands to solve the remainder of your problem (imho).

Comment: @JeffSchaller I don't think it's off-topic. smbclient is a Linux program of the samba suite; how to use that is perfectly on-topic here IMO.

Comment: @WouterVerhelst just my opinion, but there’s no smbclient problem here; that’s just the vehicle to the Windows PC. The Question is what to put in the -c option to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: @JeffSchaller you seem to be confused. The `-c` option's argument is a script that's executed by *smbclient*, not by the host that smbclient is connected to. As a pseudo-FTP client, `smbclient` allows you to do things like change directory (with the `cd` command) and copy files to your local computer. As a client for a Windows computer, smbclient uses the backslash (`\\`) as a directory separator, which makes sense. But the question is about "what commands do I give smbclient", not "what commands do I send to this Windows box", so it's perfectly on topic.

Comment: [this quote](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SMB-HOWTO-8.html) "Although you can use smbclient for testing, you will soon tire of it for real work. For that you will probably want to use the smbfs package. Smbfs comes with two simple utilties, smbmount and smbumount. They work just like mount and umount for SMB shares." leads me to ask: are you open to doing this with smbmount, or do you have to use smbclient (which apparently has a limited command set)?

Comment: Look at this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31130/show-files-from-the-last-2-days-on-a-mounted-ntfs-system). Put the list of computers in an array, mount each share in turn and then check for date/time. I haven't really look at the command usage, but it looks promising.

Comment: I think I just misinterpreted your question (again?) -- do you need to *get* (retrieve) the file, or do you just need the filename? I've extracted the filename but also shown the "get" command that you demonstrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the smbclient command-set doesn't implement a full shell, my best idea (short of smbounting the shares and using the local shell utilities), is to "parse ls".

At a high level, you'd replace the single smbclient command with two:

1. `smbclient ... dir` -- to get the file listing
2. `smbclient ... get` -- to get the oldest file

Since I don't have an environment similar to yours, here's the "guts" of what I'd replace:

```
filename=$(smbclient '\\'$IP'\C$' -W *** -U ***%*** -c "cd \*****\*****; dir" | awk -f parse-smbclient-ls)
smbclient '\\'$IP'\C$' -W *** -U ***%*** -c "cd \*****\*****; get $filename"
```

Where the contents of parse-smbclient-ls would be:

```
BEGIN {
  "date +%s" | getline oldesttime
}

/ N / {
  #                      size           thu             mar             dd              dd:dd:dd                                dddd
  if (match($0, / N +[[:digit:]]+ +[[:alpha:]]{3} [[:alpha:]]{3} +[[:digit:]]+ [[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2} [[:digit:]]{4}$/)) {
    timestamp=sprintf("%s %s %s %s %s", $(NF-4), $(NF-3), $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF)
    filename=substr($0, 3, RSTART-3)
    # trim trailing whitespace -- *** hope the real filename doesn't end in whitespace
    sub(/ +$/, "", filename);
    ("date --date='"timestamp"' +%s") | getline seconds
    if (seconds < oldesttime) {
        oldesttime=seconds
        oldestfile=filename
    }
  }
}

END {
  print oldestfile
}
```

Stepping through that awk script:

1. initialize the currently-oldest-date value to the current time; hopefully the oldest file is at least one second old
2. If the line matches `/ N /`, then we appear to be looking at a regular file (versus directory)
3. if the line matches the regular expression given (which tries to be careful to match only the N, size-in-bytes, and timestamp, followed by the end of the line `$`), then
4. extract the timestamp
5. extract the filename
6. trim trailing whitespace from the filename
7. ask GNU date to convert the file's timestamp to seconds
8. if the current file is older than what we have, save off the timestamp and filename
9. at the end, print the oldest filename

Do note that this has at least two problems that I'm aware of:

1. if the actual filename ends in whitespace (as is perfectly legal, even on Windows I believe), then this process will fail *two* ways -- the awk script trims the whitespace itself, and the command substitution will also strip trailing whitespace.
2. files that contain (some sort of) special characters get renamed; for example, when I created a file named `foo$'\n'bar`, the smbclient `dir` command instead showed me: `FKCEWC~I` as the filename.